# React-Native send file etc. like whatsapp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I would like to send files, videos and images like whatsApp does. I also want to keep sending my file in the background.

I am using react-native-fetch-blob but if I send mp4 file my chat screen stops, how can I make it function like whatsApp?

Answer (score 0):

For handling video upload in background you can use [headless-js](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android), and for optimization purpose rather sending your file as one, send it with stream and in chunks.